# compare 2 excel files by keeping 1 column fixed of 1 sheet and then comparing with another file with same col by using python

Tags: python, excel, excel-2010, xlrd

We have 2 excel files one having 7.5k records and other having 7k records. We need to compare the data by keeping one specific column as fixed from one sheet to compare with another sheet.

For Example sheet1:

```
**Emp_ID|   Name|   Phone|  Address**
-------------------------------------
1       |     A |    123 |  ABC
-------------------------------------
2       |     B |    456 |  CBD
-------------------------------------
3       |     C |    789 |  S
```

For Example sheet2:

```
**Emp_ID|   Name|   Phone|  Address**
-------------------------------------
1       |     A |    123 |  ABC
-------------------------------------
3       |     C |    789 |  S
```

Python Comparison should on the basis of Emp_ID and Emp_ID=2 should be output as missing when passing the argument as Emp_ID while executing the python script.
I am trying the same by using XLRD module, but its comparing only cell by cell instead of freezing one column and then comparing the row with other excel file.

```
def compareexcel(oldSheet, newSheet):
        rowb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(oldSheet)
        rowb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(newSheet)
        sheet1 = rowb1.sheet_by_index(0)
        sheet2 = rowb2.sheet_by_index(0)

        for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
            if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
                row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
                row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)

                for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
                    if c1 != c2:                    
                        print "Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
```

Comment: and what happens if: 1 | A | 123 | ABC but in sheet 2 - 1 | A | 333 | AAA? what's your expected end result?

Comment: Then normal comparison should take place. 
Expected end result : if any emp id is missing in sheet then comparison should not take place and only when emp_id is same the comparison should take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written one function to search for a column value into another sheet and  on the basis of that comparison would take place in compare function

```
def search(sheet2 , s):
    for row in range(sheet2.nrows):`enter code here`
        if s == sheet2.cell(row,0).value:
            return (row,0)
    return (9,9)

def compare(oldPerPaxSheet,newPerPaxSheet):
    rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(oldPerPaxSheet)
    rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(newPerPaxSheet)
    sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)

    for rownum in range(max(self.sheet1.nrows, self.sheet2.nrows)):
            if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
                    row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
                    print ("row_rb1 : "), row_rb1

                    search_str = sheet1.cell(rownum,0).value

                    r,c = search(sheet2,search_str)
                    if (c != 9):
                            row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(r)
                            for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(izip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
                                    if c1 != c2:                    
                                            print "Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2)
                    else:
                            print ("ROw does not exists in the other sheet")
                            pass
            else:
                    print ("Row {} missing").format(rownum+1)
```

Comment: This helped me solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel) for this.

I will make 2 DataFrames with `Emp_ID` as index

```
import pandas as pd

sheets = pd.read_excel(excel_filename, sheetname=[old_sheet, new_sheet], index_col=0)
sheet1 = sheets[old_sheet]
sheet2 = sheets[new_sheet]
```

I added some rows to have clearer differences

> sheet1

```
    Name    Phone   Address
Emp_ID          
1   A   123     ABC
2   B   456     CBD
3   C   789     S
5   A   123     ABC
```

> sheet2

```
    Name    Phone   Address
Emp_ID          
1   A   123     ABC
3   C   789     S
4   D   12  A
5   E   123     ABC
```

calculating the missing `Emp_ID` becomes very simple then

```
missing_in_1  = set(sheet2.index) - set(sheet1.index) 
missing_in_2  = set(sheet1.index) - set(sheet2.index)
```

> missing_in_1, missing_in_2

```
({4}, {2})
```

so sheet1 has no `Emp_ID` 4 which is in sheet2, and sheet2 lacks a 2, as expected

Then to look for the differences, we do an inner-join on the 2 sheets

```
combined = pd.merge(sheet1, sheet2, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_1', '_2'))
```

> combined

```
    Name_1  Phone_1     Address_1   Name_2  Phone_2     Address_2
Emp_ID                      
1   A   123     ABC     A   123     ABC
3   C   789     S   C   789     S
5   A   123     ABC     E   123     ABC
```

and loop over the columns of sheet1 to look for differences and save these in a `dict`

```
differences = {}
for column in sheet1.columns:
    diff = combined[column+'_1'] != combined[column+'_2']
    if diff.any():
        differences[column] = list(combined[diff].index)
```

> differences

```
{'Name': [5]}
```

If you want the whole list of differences, you change the last line to `differences[column] = combined[diff]`

> differences

```
{'Name':        
         Name_1  Phone_1 Address_1 Name_2  Phone_2 Address_2
 Emp_ID                                                    
 5           A      123       ABC      E      123       ABC}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I had to do with XLRD module only. But on the other hand i tried installing panda, but couldnt make it due to various dependencies while installing it.